# How to find out which process consume most memory and how much?

Tags: windows-7

I know one way is to look at the process explorer available on Windows but which information one should look at?

THere are private bytes and working set and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Working set is one of the best measures, but commit and paged memory tell you if you are running out of RAM and your process is running more slowly than it should. Close some programs, or get more RAM, or open less documents/tabs with that program.

Working set is the total memory allocated to all users (including you).

Peak is the maximum.

Delta register the changes in memory used (it can be a relatively small positive, negative, or zero value).

Private working set: memory allocated to you.

Commit. Virtual memory used.

Paged pool. Memory that may be used from the virtual memory (paged - simulated with hard disk).

non-paged Pool. Memory used from actual RAM memory.

Answer (score 0):

In windows-7 you can use [Perfmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Task Manager?  Go to the Processes tab, click Show processes from all users, and click Memory to sort by how much Memory consumed.

Answer (score 0):

There are countless ways. My favorite is the "Working Set" counter in the [Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86b5d116-6fb3-427b-af8c-9077162125fe) category.

See also [Memory Performance Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965225%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#process_memory_performance_information).